# Would the shape of this graph be considered normal or skewed?

Tags: statistics

[image]Would this graphs shape be considered normally distributed or skewed (positively)? At first I assumed it was skewed as all data was pushed to the left with a tail on the right side, however there is reasonable data on either side of the centre so I am unsure if it could still be normal dist?

Comment: If is time hardly would be normal.

Comment: Um, care to elaborate what you mean?